# Representation matrices of $PGL(2,\mathbb F _q)$

Tags: group-theory, reference-request, finite-groups, representation-theory

The character table of $PGL(2,\mathbb F _q)$ ($q$ a generic prime larger than $2$) is [well-known](https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Linear_representation_theory_of_projective_general_linear_group_of_degree_two_over_a_finite_field). But I need the representation matrices in my research.

The represetation matrices for dimensions $1$, $q$ and $q+1$ can be easily computed by inducing the $1$-dimensional representation of the Borel subgroup to the whole group. What left are the $(q-1)$-dimensional representations.

**Question**: How to find representation matrices for the $(q-1)$-dimensional representations of $PGL(2,\mathbb F _q)$?

Comment: Do you need them for a specific $q$ or do you want generic matrices?

Comment: The $q$ is a generic prime. (Guess I should use $p$ though).

Comment: This is, I believe, far from an easy question. I am at least 60% sure that they are not known in general, although someone else might be able to correct me. For example, when Riese proved integrality results about $SL_2(p)$ representations, his method for the discrete series representations was somewhat roundabout. You should be OK with obtaining the one that splits on restriction to $PSL$, as that is a Weil construction.

Comment: Such a character is OK. Do you have references of that character? And what about the (cuspidal) characters that does not split when restricted on $PSL$?

Comment: The cuspidal characters are also called discrete series representations. Constructions of cuspidal characters are incredibly hard, never mind cuspidal representations. It might be possible to extract the Weil characters for $SL_2(p)$ from Ward's 1972 paper 'Representations of Symplectic Groups'. Although now I think about it, the Weil representations are representations of $SL_2(p)$, not $PSL_2(p)$ anyway. Do you really really need them for your research?

Comment: You can also look into the references from Riese's paper 'On Integral Representations for SL(2,q)'.

Comment: Actually, I need the eigenvalues of $\rho(a)+\rho(b)+\rho(c)$ where $\rho$ is a representation of $PGL(2,q)$, and $a,b,c$ are specific elements in the group. I do not know whether it's possible to get the eigenvalues while avoiding the matrices.

Comment: I see no reason why you should be able to obtain those eigenvalues, although there might be a trick. I assume that $G=\langle a,b,c\rangle$, otherwise it's a lot easier!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/111496/discussion-between-leechlattice-and-david-a-craven).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The cuspidal representations of $GL(2,q)$ are constructed in [A Note on Complex Representations of $GL(2, \mathbb F_q)$](http://math.ntnu.edu.tw/%7Eli/note/REPGL2K.pdf). They are presented as complex functions on $\mathbb F_q^\times$ (hence $(q-1)$-dimensional), parameterized by a character $\nu$ of $\mathbb F_{q^2}^\times$. By requiring $\nu(x)=1$ for $x \in \mathbb F_q^\times$, the representation matrices corresponding to scalar multiplication in $GL(2,q)$ are unit matrices, thus the representation of $GL(2,q)$ can be projected onto a representation of $PGL(2,q)$.